# Terraform - Rendering Local Values and Variables to speed up development

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to render the values of Local Values and Variables? As an example, I have this file

```rb
variable "foo" {
  type = string
  default = "bar"
}

locals {
  my_var = "here is ${var.foo}"
}

# Rendered:
# my_var = "here is bar"
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do it? I've tried [terraform console](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/console.html) but it's hard to use it with complicated use-cases, such as `templatefile`, `jsonencode`, `jsondecode`, `merge` and the list goes on and on.

I need this capability to test functions that I'm not yet familiar with. Doing `terraform apply` for just checking how my functions are working is something that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What are you finding particularly difficult with `terraform console`? Can you edit your question to show a specific thing that doesn't work nicely there and how you are trying to use it with `terraform console`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I was trying to render a template with nested values and I had trouble using `jsonencode`, `jsondecode` and `templatefile`, it was tough doing it with `terraform console` I wrote this project - https://github.com/unfor19/tfcoding - which is like https://www.katacoda.com/courses/terraform/playground but locally and fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed something like https://www.katacoda.com/courses/terraform/playground but for local usage with fast results.

I created this project - https://github.com/unfor19/tfcoding - which brings up a Docker container that watches for changes in the file `tfcoding.tf` and renders the Local Values automatically upon saving this file.

Demo:

[image: tfcoding-demo]